# WPF MVVM: View's ListBox with source deep in Model. How to implement?

Tags: wpf, list, mvvm, viewmodel, observablecollection

I'm new to WPF. I need to Bind UI's ListBox to the source that is deep in Model Layer.

App scheme is on picture below. Desc:

My `MainWindowViewModel` Class has a `Scheduler` Property (`Scheduler` Class in Model layer).

`Scheduler` Class has a `CurrentParser` Property (`Parser` Class in Model layer).

`Parser` Class has a `Result` field (`ParserResultMetaData` Class in Model layer).

`ParserResultMetaData` Class has a `Log` field (`Log` is a `List(Of String)`)

Log can be changed only programmatically from model layer (Parser adds lines during it's work).

So my question is how can I bind my ListBox to this List to match MVVM pattern.
As I get it now, ViewModel must have an ObservableCollection(Of String) witch is a copy of my List(Of String) from Model layer.

[image]

Comment: Your question basically is; How to bind list from Viewmodel to View? This binding can be modify either in code and in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you need to notify the UI when a line is added to the collection. There are multiple ways to achieve this, but if the collection is modified from within the model layer, you need a mechanism for communicating this to other layers in one way or another.

- Use an ObservableCollection in your Model layer.

While types like `ObservableCollection` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` are widely used in MVVM architectures, they are not specific to them and in some cases it can make sense to use them in the model layer directly. Using an `ObservableCollection` in your `Parser` class is one way to provide this notification mechanism. You can then bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to `Scheduler.Parser.Result.Log` directly and it will update accordingly.

- Create a wrapper property in your ViewModel.

If you don't want to use an `ObservableCollection` in your model, you can expose the List via a property in your ViewModel, for example:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ParserLog 
{
    get { return Scheduler.Parser.Result.Log; }
}
```

Then you need to manually notify the UI when an item is added, so you're gonna need an event (or something equivalent) which tells your ViewModel that the list changed and it needs to raise the `PropertyChanged` Event for the `ParserLog` property. Add code like this in your ViewModel:

```
    this.Scheduler.Parser.ResultUpdated += (s, e) => this.RaisePropertyChanged("ParserLog");
```

This will tell the ListBox to update the items from the ParserLog property.